# Reference to non-static member function must be called(vector)

Tags: c++, vector

i have a class which named `class nameAndLastname` and it has a

```
class nameAndLastname
{
private:
    vector<string> Names_Lastname();


public:

    void get();
    void Delete();
    string search();
};
```

`private:vector<string> Names_Lastnames();` and at first i got some names from another function and put them in `vector<string> Names_Lastnames()`

```
    void nameAndLastname::get()
{
    int SizeOFNames;
    cout<<"enter number of the names and last names";
    cin>>SizeOFNames;
    vector<string> Names_Lastnames(SizeOFNames);
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;
    string fileName,Line;
    cout<<"whats the file name?:";
    cin>>fileName;
    inFile.open(fileName);
    getline(inFile,Line);
    cout<<"the first line of the file is:"<<endl;
    cout<<Line<<endl;
    cout<<"outputfilename?"<<endl;
    cin>>fileName;
    outFile.open(fileName);
    outFile<<Line<<endl;
    cout<<"now enter the names and last names";
    for (int i=0; i<=SizeOFNames; i++) {
        getline(cin,Names_Lastnames[i]);
        outFile<<Names_Lastnames[i]<<endl;
    }
    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();





}
```

and now i want to delete one of the names that user want to delete and i write this

```
void nameAndLastname::Delete(){
    string rname;
    cin>>rname;
    auto itr = find(Names_Lastnames.begin(), Names_Lastnames.end(), rname);
    if (itr != Names_Lastnames.end()) Names_Lastnames.erase(itr);
//error~>Reference to non-static member function must be called; did you mean to call it with no arguments?
//Use of undeclared identifier 'Names_Lastnames'
}
```

but i have this error "Reference to non-static member function must be called" .
i want to know how can i access to my vector from class named `class nameAndLastname` with reference

Comment: please include a [mcve] and the full error message

Comment: [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Comment: ``vector<string> Names_Lastname();`` is not a vector variable. It is a function that returns a vector.

Comment: @sp2danny rather "least vexing parse", there is not much ambiguity, `Names_Lastname` is declared as a method, no way to parse this as a member variable unless I miss some new syntax

Comment: @john i dont want too use it in two different class i want to use it in one calls in two different function

Comment: "two different class" ?!? do you want `NamesLastname` to be a member variable or a method?

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `Names_Lastnames` as a function that takes no parameters and returns a `vector<string>`.
(You did not put anything into it - if it looks like you did, you put your names into a vector with the same name.)

Remove the parentheses to make it a `vector<string>`.

Comment: @kiaazad It's exactly as I suspected - you're putting them into a local variable called "Names_Lastnames", but your member with that name is a function (and the two are completely unrelated.)

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
class nameAndLastname
{
private:
    vector<string> Names_Lastname; // <--- no ()


public:

    void get();
    void Delete();
    string search();
};

void nameAndLastname::get()
{
    int SizeOFNames;
    cout<<"enter number of the names and last names";
    cin>>SizeOFNames;
    Names_Lastname.resize(SizeOFNames); // <--- resize class vector
    ...
}

void nameAndLastname::Delete(){
    string rname;
    cin>>rname;
    auto itr = find(Names_Lastname.begin(), Names_Lastname.end(), rname);
    if (itr != Names_Lastname.end()) 
        Names_Lastname.erase(itr);
}
```

As is common for newbies you had multiple mistakes and misunderstandings ganging up on you.

This version declares the vector (correctly without `()`) in the class where all methods can access it, and resizes that vector (instead of redeclaring it) in the `get` method

Answer (score 0):

```
void nameAndLastname::get()
{
//...
vector<string> Names_Lastnames(SizeOFNames);
//..
} // the scope of Names_Lastnames ends here.
```

It seems like, you are referring a member variable with a similar name:Names_Lastname. If yes, correct it. Then if Names_Lastname is the variable, it is declared like a function in the class body. The parenthesis is not required. Hope you will try and repost the question if required.